# NLA editor, default value before NLA strip starts

Tags: animation, error, nla-editor

**System Information**
Operating system: Windows 10

**Blender Version**
2.83.0

**Short description of error**
Animation in NLA editor goes wrong

**Exact steps for others to reproduce the error**
The object's position (rotation) is default instead of being in the 1 key state before the NLA start. I've made a sreenshot to clarify my problem.
[image: Illustrative screenshot, wrong behaviour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour can be set with the extrapolation menu of the "N" panel, strip properties.

[image]